# Extreme Slowness on Oracle Database Connection

Tags: java, oracle, performance, jdbc, ojdbc

I have a remote Linux server and I want to connect to an Oracle database which is in another server, using ojdbc7 lib

When I try to connect directly to the database from my Windows PC, using the same client and ojdbc7 lib, I have reasonable connection time.  [image]

Now, when I want to connect through my linux server, I get extreme slowness, just in the connection time.  [image]. Once connected, the execution is OK.

I have read about adding `-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/urandom` like in [this post](https://community.oracle.com/thread/993619), but nothing happened.

What could I do to fix this delay in setting up a connection from linux?

Comment: Please don't post images from things you could simply have posted as text. Replace those images with the text equivalent.

Comment: You call almost 1 second acceptable for establishing a connection? 40 seconds is out of the ballpark, but 1 second is long too

Comment: Someone has already edited out your apology for "broken english" (which, by the way, you were not using), but I'll take just a moment to say that your English is just fine, that you're communicating well, and that if you hadn't mentioned it I wouldn't have known you were not a native English speaker. The same goes for all you other non-native-English speakers here (and elsewhere on the net) - you're doing a lot better than many of us would do if we had to try to communicate in your native tongue. Thanks.

Comment: On the same server gpp... What is the times for say sqlplus to connect ?

Comment: There are many possibilities where this delay might come from. I'd analyze the network traffic between your linux box and the DB server, using a sniffer, e.g. Wireshark. When studying its output you'll most probably find a single interaction that takes up 40 seconds, or (more likely) doesn't get an answer and runs into a timeout after 40 seconds.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Unfortunately, the server doesn't have sqlplus and we Can't install it there :/

Comment: We can't install tcpdump for network traffic analyze neither :/

Comment: With all the restrictions you have, I doubt you will be able to fix it.  Better ask that system's administrator to look into your problem.  I notice you are connecting to port 1525.  I haven't seen that port number in a very long time.  But since it's working on your PC, it shouldn't matter.  Can you compare "java -version" on the server and on your PC?

Comment: if it was me I would try a "traceroute" command from my PC (I think it is tracert from DOS) and then from the linux box and make sure it is not a network thing

Comment: Any updates? I have the same issue, when running on linux host in docker container

Answer (score 0):

Close, but no cigar: it's "file:///dev/urandom", or one of the variations, see eg. https://anirban-m.blogspot.com/2014/03/jdbc-connection-reset-error-java.html

Comment: Thanks you for your reply. I have also tried, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you add the output from "ls -l /dev/urandom" to your question?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are using version 12.1.0.1.

There was an Oracle bug where JDBC connections could take excessive times because the data being sent required the listener to perform a DNS lookup for each connection and that could apparently be very slow for some reason.

The bug was fixed in 12.2 and there is a back-ported fix (patch) for 12.1.0.2.

In the meantime, try getting your Linux admin to go through the process of tuning DNS lookups on that server.  E.g., tune `/etc/resolv.conf` or enable the name service cache daemon.  I'm not really expert in Linux administration so I can't help you.  But based on the problem and the version you are using, that's where I'd look.

Comment: I went back and looked up that bug number.  It was bug 18369949.  It looks like it was fixed in version 12.1.0.2 of the JDBC driver.  So, you might fix it by just updating your JDBC driver (to at least 12.1.0.2, preferably to 12.2).